# Is iphone needed just to build an archive in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm new in ios development. I have an existing app in android made from flutter that I want to build an os version of. My problem is I have this errors when trying to create an archive build.

```
Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

No profiles for 'com.build.app' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.build.app'.
```

I already have an apple developer team but I can't create identifiers. Its always saying

```
An App ID with Identifier 'com.build.app' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

Do i really need to have an iphone just to make an archive? Is there any other way cause I don't have an iphone.

Comment: No, you do not need an iPhone for a build.

Comment: You will need to add the udid for at least one iPhone to your  developer account.  If you don't have one maybe you can ask someone you know who has an iPhone for their udid.

Comment: No, you need just a simulator. In fact, you can't archive a project when a physical device is selected for the build in xCode.

Comment: you really need to use different string for your app identifier, they are global and this string is used already

Comment: @Paulw11 Is it have to be in my developers account? I'm a part of a team. Can one registered device be use by all the team? Sorry I'm really new at this.

Comment: Yes, you only need one device in the account for everyone.